# CRM workflow to send a report attachment to users

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have written some code to send an email attachment through CRM to a specific user, using a workflow, the attachment is a transcript report which contains 2 sub reports in order to get some data about students. The problem that i have is that the email is not delivered and the attachment breaks indicating this:

> "Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'Subreport2', located at:
>   /StudentReports/StudentAddress. Please check the log files for more
>   information."

The log files contain no useful information. Here is the code:

```
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Crm.Workflow;
using NUP.CRM.DAL;
using NUP.CRM.DAL.Utility;
using NUP.CRM.Utilities;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Workflow.ComponentModel;



namespace NUP.CRM.WorkFlows

{
    /// <summary>
    /// Sends transcript of a given assessment board and ac. year as attachment to email
    /// </summary>
    [CrmWorkflowActivity("Send email with Report Attached", "NUP")]
    public class SendReport : Activity
    {
        public static DependencyProperty AcademicYearProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AcademicYear", typeof(string), typeof(SendReport));
        public static DependencyProperty AssBoardProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AssBoard", typeof(string), typeof(SendReport));
        public static DependencyProperty EmailAddressTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EmailAddressType", typeof(string), typeof(SendReport));
        public static DependencyProperty EmailBodyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EmailBody", typeof(string), typeof(SendReport));
        public static DependencyProperty IsPositiveProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsPositive", typeof(CrmBoolean), typeof(SendReport));
        public static DependencyProperty ReportNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ReportName", typeof(string), typeof(SendReport));
        public static DependencyProperty ReportPathProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ReportPath", typeof(string), typeof(SendReport));
        public static DependencyProperty SenderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Sender", typeof(Lookup), typeof(SendReport));
        public static DependencyProperty SendFromAddressProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SendFromAddress", typeof(string), typeof(SendReport));
        public static DependencyProperty SubjectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Subject", typeof(string), typeof(SendReport));

        protected override ActivityExecutionStatus Execute(ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)
        {
            IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetService<IContextService>().Context;
            ICrmService service = context.CreateCrmService();

            byte[] report = ReportUtility.GetReport(
                ReportPath,
                ReportUtility.Formats.PDF,
                new string[] { "contactid", "AcYear", "IsPositive", "AssBoard" },
                new string[] {
                         context.PrimaryEntityId.ToString(),
                         AcademicYear.ToString(),
                         IsPositive.Value.ToString(),
                         AssBoard }
                );


            string addressToUse = DynamicEntityUtility.GetContactEmailOfType(service, context.PrimaryEntityId, EmailAddressType);

            EmailUtility emailUtility =
                new EmailUtility(service, context.UserId, context.PrimaryEntityId, addressToUse);

            List<EmailUtility.Attachment> attachments =
                new List<EmailUtility.Attachment>()
            {
                    new EmailUtility.Attachment(ReportName, report)
                };

            emailUtility.Send(Subject, attachments);

            return ActivityExecutionStatus.Closed;

        }

        [CrmInput("AcademicYear")]
        public string AcademicYear
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)base.GetValue(AcademicYearProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(AcademicYearProperty, value);
            }
        }

        [CrmInput("AssBoard")]
        public string AssBoard
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)base.GetValue(AssBoardProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(AssBoardProperty, value);
            }
        }

        [CrmInput("EmailAddressType")]
        public string EmailAddressType
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)base.GetValue(EmailAddressTypeProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(EmailAddressTypeProperty, value);
            }
        }

        [CrmInput("EmailBody")]
        public string EmailBody
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)base.GetValue(EmailBodyProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(EmailBodyProperty, value);
            }
        }

        [CrmInput("IsPositive")]
        public CrmBoolean IsPositive
        {
            get
            {
                return (CrmBoolean)base.GetValue(IsPositiveProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(IsPositiveProperty, value);
            }
        }

        [CrmInput("ReportName")]
        public string ReportName
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)base.GetValue(ReportNameProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(ReportNameProperty, value);
            }
        }

        [CrmInput("ReportPath")]
        public string ReportPath
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)base.GetValue(ReportPathProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(ReportPathProperty, value);
            }
        }

        [CrmReferenceTarget("systemuser"), CrmInput("Sender")]
        public Lookup Sender
        {
            get
            {
                return (Lookup)base.GetValue(SenderProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(SenderProperty, value);
            }
        }

        [CrmInput("SendFromAddress")]
        public string SendFromAddress
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)base.GetValue(SendFromAddressProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(SendFromAddressProperty, value);
            }
        }

        [CrmInput("Subject")]
        public string Subject
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)base.GetValue(SubjectProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(SubjectProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a problem with CRM, it's a problem in report - the error clearily states that you have some error in your subreport. You should check the logs for your ReportingServices, they should have more useful information

Comment: When i run the parent report for a specific student through CRM it shows up correctly, so it must be something wrong in the workflow creation

Comment: You did not include any code regarding report creation (you are calling some mysterious function GetReport from ReportUtility class, that's not enough). I guess that under the hood you are calling the service to generate PDF document - the question is what happens if you call this service using for example Fiddler - you can't compare this with using report generation in CRM which does not use service directly but ReportViewer control, so your test did not prove anything

Comment: Is this crm version 4?

Comment: Yes it is crm version 4

Comment: Crm 4 and online ??

Comment: Yeap exactly ...

Comment: Any solutions???

Comment: You are expecting Solutions yet you się not provide the code you use for report generation and you used wrong tag (online does not mean IFD configuration for on-premise CRM which I bet you have). Please show some more specific code your question does not have any useful information to help you

Comment: the report was designed in visual studio using the report manager, what exactly do you want? the whole XML code?

Comment: please someone tell me what code you need exactly

Comment: hello, is there anyone willing to help with this matter? i still did not find a resolution